# A tip to verify property of a finite field in Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-fields

Let $m$ be a prime number with the following operations in the set $\mathbb{Z}_m = \{\bar{0}, \bar{1}, \dots, \bar{m - 1}\}$:

- $\bar{a} + \bar{b} = \bar{c}$, where $c$ is the modulus of $a + b$ by $m$.
- $\bar{a} \cdot \bar{b} = \bar{d}$, where $d$ is the modulus of $a \cdot b$ by $m$.

The task is to verify the field property

$(\bar{a} + \bar{b}) + \bar{c} = \bar{a} + (\bar{b} + \bar{c})$

I can't view any initial step to verify that. Anyone could give me a tip?

Comment: The set $\;\Bbb Z_m\;$ won't usually be a field. You're missing a very important condition. It though will always be a ring.

Comment: Thanks @Joanpemo. Corrected.

Comment: The property you want to check must be true in **any** group, in this case the commutative group of the ring $\;\Bbb Z_m\;$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $\;\overline a=a+rm\;,\;\;\overline b=b+sm\;,\;\;\overline c=c+tm\;,\;\;0\le a,b,c<m\;$, and everything integers. Now remember that associativity exists in the ring of integers $\;\Bbb Z\;$ and thus we can put parenthese as we want when working there:

$$\overline a+\left(\overline b+\overline c\right)=a+rm+(b+sm+c+tm)=a+b+c+(r+s+t)m=$$

$$\left(a+rm+b+rm\right)+c+tm=\left(\overline a+\overline b\right)+\overline c$$

After this, you still need to check your ring is a field by showing that any non-zero element has a *multiplicative* inverse. Bezout identity can be helpful.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Joanpemo. I was wondering here on something like this. In the first expression you mean $\bar{a} = \bar{a} + rm$ right?

Comment: @Caco Thank you. Edited.

Comment: I was referring my textbook and saw that in fact what we have is that $\bar{a} = \bar{a + rm}, p \in \mathbb{Z}$. Now I didn't understand why you can write $\bar{a} = a + rm$ and work with normal properties of $\mathbb{Z}$. Is that possible?

Comment: You continue to mix notation, but it doesn't matter: to work with  the ring of integers modulo $\;m\;$ you need representatives of the left cosets of $\;m\Bbb Z\;$ in $\;\Bbb Z\;$ , so any number in $\;\Bbb Z\;$ can be written as I wrote above. For example, $\;18=4+2\cdot 7\implies \overline{18}=4\pmod 7\;$